# CustomSQLUtil gets null value during query retrieval with Liferay 7

Tags: jakarta-ee, liferay, liferay-7, liferay-service-builder

Whereas I had no problem with the CustomSQLUtil class in Liferay 6.2, I meet a problem with the new version of this class in Liferay 7. Indeed, the get method returns null instead of the expected query.

Does someone has reproduced this ?

Here is the description for my last test in Eclipse Mars :

1. In my Liferay workspace, I added the following line in the build.gradle of the service module

compileOnly group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.portal.dao.orm.custom.sql", version: "1.0.5"

2. After a gradle refresh, I am able to use the CustomSQLUtil class in my FooFinderImpl class to retrieve the appropriate query.
3. This query has been written in a default.xml file which is dropped into the src/custom-sql folder as mentionned in the Liferay 7 documentation :

https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/custom-sql

I've tried with many places (in META-INF, in ressources..), I've even tried to extend the CustomSQL native class to get the configuration, but the get method of the CustomSQLUtil class returns always null instead of the sql query.

PS : I've noticed that this new "CustomSQLUtil.get" method now takes 2 parameters, a class is requested in addition to the query id. In this class parameter, I put the "Foo.class" value.

Does someone know if there is a configuration to do ? Does the classpath or bundlecontext has to be configured ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make it work  add the `custom-sql/default.xml` in the `foo-service/src/main/resources`  then in `FooFinderImpl`  use the CustomSQLUtil this way

```
CustomSQLUtil.get(getClass(),CONSTANT_QUERY_ID); //id of query in default.xml
```

this is an example on github https://github.com/bruinen/liferay-services-example

Comment: It works ! My error was to put the Foo.class argument instead of the FooFinderImpl.class.
Thank you Romeo !

Answer (score -1):

Try avoiding using CustomSQLUtil. Instead try using query directly inside your finder method like 
           String sql="select * from Foo_Foo where name=?" 
Hope that helps!!

Comment: I agree it works without the CustomSQLUtil class but I would like to keep sql queries in a separate xml file like introduced in the Liferay documentation.